# Enforcing the value of a Type variable as special base type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, module

I have realized my module system by forcing modules to implement an abstract class, which contains mandatory methods which will be called by the base application. Now I want to realize a configuration form for each module. I thought about returning the type of the form as a property of my module skeleton class:

```
public abstract class Module
{
    public abstract Type ConfigurationForm { get; }
}
```

When displaying the configuration form, I simply instantiate a Form of this type and call the `Show()` method.

The problem is, I want to force the module to return a Type which is a sub class of `System.Windows.Forms.Form`, as the call would fail otherwise. What is the correct way to enforce this?

I thought about encapsulating the ConfigurationForm property in another property, which checks if it is inherited from `Form`, but I don't think this is a clean way to accomplish this.

Comment: Is there any reason that the `ConfigurationForm` property can't use the return type of `Form`?

Comment: The type of the configuration form changes from module to module, since it is inherited from `Form`. Or do you mean I should instantiate the form itself in the module code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could accomplish this with a generic type parameter

```
public abstract class Module<F> where F : Form
{
    public Type ConfigurationForm { get { return typeof(F); } }
}
```

But really this might make more sense:

```
public abstract class Module
{
    public abstract Form CreateConfigurationForm();
}
```

Edit: The advantage of using the 2nd option is that you can write code to work with your Module class without having to know specifically which kind of module you are dealing with

Comment: Yes, definitely! Don't know why I wanted to create the instance of the form outside the module... Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to restrict a function to return `Type`, which represents a type that inherits from `Form`. What you could do it to return the form directly:

```
public abstract Form CreateConfigurationForm();
```

or a factory method (or alternatively, factory class):

```
public abstract Func<Form> ConfigurationFormCreator();
```

Another option would be to use generics, as erash suggested.